# 403 forbidden when pushing to Bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Bitbucket apparently changed something, and I have been googling for answers but there are so many topics of logins failing to Bitbucket that I don't even know which to start with. Most of them are spread out over the past few years. I don't see anything recent-- as in, something that would break logins between March and today.

`hg push` is the command I am using to push changes. It fails with an HTTP 403; the only output is "`abort: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`".

I am using the same settings I have for years. My push process worked as recently as March.

I can log into the website using my email and password, which is different than the username I used to use to push.

Comment: You really need to make this question more specific. When you try to push exactly what output do you get from `hg`? Can you log in to the bitbucket web portal and perform tasks there? What authentication format are you using, SSH keys? What repo url format are you using, http or ssh?

Comment: I'm not using git, I'm using mercurial.  The only output is literally "abort: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden".  I am using the same settings I have for years.

Comment: The best authoritative documentation for Bitbucket would be here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/search/?productName=Bitbucket&queryString=authentication alter that to suit your BB version as needed

Comment: `hg` has a verbose flag, does that provide any additional output to help define or solve the problem? https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html

Comment: That gives me more information about the push itself, before the 403, but only the 403 again as the error itself.

Comment: @Freiheit I added the command I used and removed a paragraph of unnecessary whining to hopefully make this more useful to people having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://bitbucket.org/blog/sunsetting-mercurial-support-in-bitbucket

> After much consideration, we've decided to remove Mercurial support from Bitbucket Cloud and its API. Mercurial features and repositories will be officially deprecated on July 1, 2020.

You are getting a 403 because Bitbucket no longer supports Mercurial. The July 1st 2020 cutoff date fits between your March 2020 and now (July 29th 2020) time window.